# EOFError when running feature tests with Capybara and headless Chrome

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

EDIT: It turns out this whole problem was due to a hidden and poorly named monkey patch in our project for WEBrick, which Capybara uses as its default web server. StackOverflow isn't letting me delete the question, so be wary when reading further.

We're attempting to upgrade our Ruby version from 2.2.7 to 2.4.3. The app itself is running fine, but all of our feature tests that run via Capybara and headless Chrome (with Chromedriver) are suddenly failing.

Here's an example of the exact error we're seeing:

```
Failures:

  1) New UI - Settings Page - API with an unpermitted tier clicking on the "Request API Key" button shows a feature popup
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace

          EOFError:
            end of file reached

     1.2) Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace

          EOFError:
            end of file reached
```

And here's how we're configuring the Selenium driver for headless Chrome:

```
CHROME_BINARY = ENV.fetch('CHROME_BINARY', '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome')

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      'chromeOptions' => {
        'binary' => CHROME_BINARY,
        'args' => %w(no-sandbox disable-gpu window-size=1440,900 headless)
      }
    )
  )
end
```

Ruby version: 2.4.3

Chromedriver version: 2.35.528157

Capybara version: 2.18.0

RSpec version: 3.7.0

selenium-webdriver: 3.9.0

Chrome: 64.0.3282.167

All other research I've done indicates that updating Chromedriver to the latest version will solve this issue, but we're already using the latest version (2.3.5).

I haven't been able to find a way to get any more of a backtrace for the above error. The spec isn't even getting to the point where it's loading anything from the database, it just fails immediately.

Another thing to note: this same exact behavior is occurring both on our CI server and on our local development machines. We use CircleCI with a Dockerized Linux container, and MacOS Sierra/High Sierra for our development machines.

We are not using chromedriver-helper or any other gem which installs chromedriver automatically. Installation of chromedriver was done either by `brew install chromedriver` or by downloading the latest chromedriver from the chromedriver website and placing in our `$PATH`.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?  Also are you absolutely sure you’re using chromedriver 2.35?  If you’re using `chromedriver-helper` it’s easy to think you’re running one version when it’s actually another - try `bundle exec chromedriver -v` to confirm

Comment: Also, what version of selenium-webdriver?

Comment: We are using `ChromeDriver 2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef)`

`selenium-webdriver (3.9.0)`

Comment: Echoing what Konstantin said:

`± % chrome --version
Google Chrome 64.0.3282.167`

`± % bundle exec chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef)`

`selenium-webdriver version 3.9.0`

Added this info to the original question

Comment: 99% of the time this is caused by mismatched chromedriver version, .9% by a system running out of resources, and then .1% by weird things that seem to go away on their own.  Are you using the `chromedriver-helper` or `webdrivers` gems (or any other gem that attempts to manage the version of chromedriver being used)?

Comment: I am not seeing either of those gems, and when I grep for "driver" here is what comes up from Gemfile.lock:

      selenium-webdriver (3.9.0)
      websocket-driver (0.6.5)

Comment: @KonstantinGredeskoul one last thing to check and then I'm out of guesses - do you have a `$HOME/.chromedriver-helper` directory, and if yes is there anything in it?

Comment: We don't use chromedriver-helper -- there is no `$HOME/.chromedriver-helper` directory. Another thing to note is that this same exact failure behavior is happening on our CI server (CircleCI, which uses a Dockerized Linux container), and on our development machines (MacOS Sierra/High Sierra).

Comment: @JordanBrown Have you tried running rspec with the `--backtrace` option to disable backtrace filtering and see if it will give you the location of the code producing the error?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Running with `--backtrace` unfortunately does not provide any additional information. Do you know of any other way to get debug information?

Comment: @JordanBrown You can try setting the environment variable DEBUG to something when running the test.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, after nearly a whole day of stepping through code execution, we found the location that the error was being raised without a backtrace: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_3/lib/net/protocol.rb#L185

I'll follow up with an answer that provides more details for others that may run into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE: the source of this problem was a monkeypatch to WEBrick. It was poorly named, and located in an unusual location and the author is no longer on the team. A good reminder that monkeypatches should be avoided at all costs.**

---

*Original answer:*

I’ve been working with Jordan (OP) on the issue. While we haven’t found the root cause, we have found where the EOFError with no backtrace came from.

The following code can be found in Ruby’s standard lib: `Net::BufferedIO#rbuf_fill`

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_3/lib/net/protocol.rb#L185

```
# callers do not care about backtrace, so avoid allocating for it
raise EOFError, 'end of file reached', []
```

My guess is that the author of this code expected that this error would be rescued at some point. Perhaps there is a bug that allowed the error to reach us, and without a backtrace.

As I said, we never found the root cause. We did however narrow it down to the point that we were able to find an acceptable work around. The issue appears to be related to Webrick which is the server that capybara will use by default if it is not specified otherwise

- When a  new capybara session is initialized, an instance of Capybara::Server is ‘booted’ this was webrick in our case: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.18_stable/lib/capybara/session.rb#L88
- Part of the boot process is to check if the server is “responsive”: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.18_stable/lib/capybara/server.rb#L105
- The responsive method makes a `get` request to the server (127.0.0.1): https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.18_stable/lib/capybara/server.rb#L82
- At this point the rest is in ruby’s http lib. Eventually it fails with the EOFError here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_3/lib/net/protocol.rb#L185

I assume that Webrick responded abnormally, or did not respond at all. If anyone has further insight on the matter, I’d love to learn.

In our case the workaround was simple. The app was already using puma in other environments, so we decided to try puma with capybara to see if it’d get us around this problem:

```rb
Capybara.server = :puma
```

Because Capybara’s rack server is no longer used, we’re no longer affected.

If anyone else runs into the same problem or has ideas regarding the root cause, please share!

Edit 1:

While stepping through code execution, I grabbed the result of `caller` when I reached `rbuf_fill`. For those that are interested, I've uploaded it here: https://gist.github.com/benjaminwood/c7c0d39fcfb2efd8a9085874cac07c36

Edit 2:

Updated info regarding Webrick as Capybara's default server. Thanks @Thomas Walpole for clarifying that.

Edit 3:

Add note regarding resolution (it was a monkeypatch).

Comment: Just to clarify - Capybara doesn't actually implement a rack server. If you don't specify `:puma` then it would use the default `WEBrick` (part of the ruby standard library).  If you have a reproducible example of this problem please file an issue at the Capybara project so it can be investigated.

Comment: Quick question about this.  Are you using WebMock or anything similar and blocking/modifying connections, especially connections to 127.0.01/localhost?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWalpole for clarifying! My understanding was not clear on that. I've updated my post to reflect Webrick as the default server.

Comment: Also, yes WebMock was in the picture but I too was suspicious of it. So, I removed it and ensured that the error still occurred. I updated my post with a trace (gist link) that might be interesting to you. You'll see webmock in the mix, but that is because I grabbed this trace before removing it. I will see if I can reproduce the problem in a clean environment.

Comment: Found the root cause! it was a poorly named/located monkeypatch to WEBrick (in our app). Uhhg, feels bad man. Thanks for your help Thomas, it was very kind. Misc question for anyone, what is the proper thing to do in this situation? Delete the question? It is not particularly useful to anyone else now that we know the root cause. May do more harm than good at this point.

Comment: I would say if the WEBrick patch has been suggested anywhere else (blog post, etc) then update the answer with details of the patch and why it caused an issue. If it was strictly an in house patch, that can’t be detailed in the answer, then deleting the question might make sense

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thanks. We can't find this monkeypatch anywhere else. I'll coordinate with the OP regarding the removal of the question. Thanks again for your help!